# Reversing a serial communication with two inputs

Tags: decryption, serial-communication, protocol, packet, communication

I'm making a device that needs me to transfer some sort of initiation code like handshaking to start further communications.
There is 2 inputs and 2 outputs the first output is pretty similar to a two's compliment which only works on even numbers and copy the value into the odd numbers.

But the second output is more complicated it is a combination of the first input and the second one and if the second input is 0 the second output is equal to the first output, let's see some examples:

```
Input 1          Output 1                  Input 2           Output 2

0- 00000000      1- 00000001     ------    8- 00001000      33- 00100001      
1- 00000001      5- 00000101     ------    8- 00001000      37- 00100101      
2- 00000010      5- 00000101     ------    8- 00001000      37- 00100101      
3- 00000011      9- 00001001     ------    8- 00001000      57- 00111001      
4- 00000100      9- 00001001     ------    8- 00001000      57- 00111001      
5- 00000101      21- 00010101     ------    8- 00001000      53- 00110101      
6- 00000110      21- 00010101     ------    8- 00001000      53- 00110101      
7- 00000111      17- 00010001     ------    8- 00001000      49- 00110001      
8- 00001000      17- 00010001     ------    8- 00001000      73- 01001001      
9- 00001001      21- 00010101     ------    8- 00001000      77- 01001101
```

This was the outputs for input 2 equal 8

```
Input 1           Output 1                    Input 2           Output 2

25- 00011001      85- 01010101   ------      31- 00011111      248- 11111000      
26- 00011010      85- 01010101     ------    31- 00011111      245- 11110101      
27- 00011011      73- 01001001     ------    31- 00011111      242- 11110010      
28- 00011100      73- 01001001     ------    31- 00011111      239- 11101111      
29- 00011101      69- 01000101     ------    31- 00011111      236- 11101100      
30- 00011110      69- 01000101     ------    31- 00011111      233- 11101001      
31- 00011111      65- 01000001     ------    31- 00011111      230- 11100110      
32- 00100000      65- 01000001     ------    31- 00011111      195- 11000011      
33- 00100001      69- 01000101     ------    31- 00011111      192- 11000000      
34- 00100010      69- 01000101     ------    31- 00011111      61- 00111101      
35- 00100011      73- 01001001     ------    31- 00011111      58- 00111010      
36- 00100100      73- 01001001     ------    31- 00011111      55- 00110111
```

Here also you can find some different inputs and outputs while holding one input constant and the others change:

[Input2=16](http://pastebin.com/KpJLV4Tu),

[Input 2=5](http://pastebin.com/hpfc99MF),

Input 1=2, link: pastebin.com/k5D5J1d5

Any help on a way to find the protocol for the outputs or the formula between them would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are making the device? Or are you reversing a device?

Comment: There are different devices connected to a main one and I'm gonna make a new one to work with the main unit but there is this first negotiation problem.